# Очистится ли оперативная память после завершения функции? Golang

Tags: golang

Пример функции:

```
func (a *SomeStruct) SomeFunction() {
    var data SomeType
    GetSomeData(&data)
    a.books = data.books
}
```

В переменную `data` помещаются очень большие данные. Очень не хотелось бы чтобы эти данные висели просто так в памяти занимая её. Могу ли я быть уверен, что после завершения функции данные будут удалены из оперативной памяти?

Comment: нет, не можете. GC запускается тогда, когда он считает нужным. Нужна большая точность - используйте языки без GC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать принудительный вызов сборщика мусора

```
runtime.GC()
```

Это вам ничего не гарантирует, но с большой вероятностью лишние данные будут удалены именно в этот момент, а не останутся занимать память.